# Use Slicers's Selection in Formula or in VBA

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a pretty complex Data Model (built into PowerPivot), where I have some slicers in a Dashboard.
All nice and dandy, however, I want those slicers to be applied to another Table which is Not (and can not be) part of the DataModel.

Therefore, I am using an Excel UDF to capture the slicers’ selections.
The part that I’m struggling with begins here. I need to use the selections that I capture from the slicers and use VBA to filter the UnLinked Table, OR use a SUMPRODUCT/SUMIFS formula to calculate the results I want from the UnLinkedTable.
For example, if in the “PRODUCTS” Slicer I select “A”, “B”, “C” and “D”, my UDF formula returns: “A, B, C, D”. 
If everything is selected in the slicer, the formula returns “All Items”.

Now, how do I filter in VBA the UnLinkedTable[PRODUCT] column using that “A, B, C, D” result, or how do I write a SUMPRODUCT or SUMIFS formula in Excel? Keep in mind that I have multiple slicers and multiple columns in the UnLinked table.
I highly appreciate your help!

Comment: so you asked 7 questions before this one and never ever accepted a single answer.. hmm...

Comment: Just to be clear, when you say 'Table' do you mean Excel Table (aka a ListObject)? Or are you talking about a PivotTable?

Comment: I mean an Excel Table, not a PivotTable

Answer (score 0):

I manage to solve my problem with a bit of VBA.
If anyone is interested in the solution, here it is:

```
[SelectionsInSlicerBrand] -> this is the named range for the cell where my UDF brings the slicer selection
BrandFilters = Split([SelectionsInSlicerBrand], ",")
If [SelectionsInSlicerBrand] <> "All Items" Then
 ActiveSheet.ListObjects("TableFilterVBA").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=(BrandFilters), Operator:=xlFilterValues
 Else
 ActiveSheet.ListObjects("TableFilterVBA").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1
End If
```

However, I now have a different issue. I have tested my Slicer UDF formula on a normal PivotTable, and it worked just fine. However, when I create a PowerPivot PivotTable, the UDF doesn’t work anymore.
Based on what I read on the following link, it might have to do with the fact that the PowerPivot PivotTable is OLAP based, so I need to use SlicerCacheLevel, not SlicerCache, like my UDF uses: [PowerPivot Slicer selection based on cell value using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28718295/powerpivot-slicer-selection-based-on-cell-value-using-vba)
I will post here the full code for my UDF which again, brings the selection of a slicer of a normal pivot table just fine. If you can please change it to work for a PowerPivot as well, that’d be amazing. The UDF is found here: 'http://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/slicers05.asp

```
Public Function GetSelectedSlicerItems(SlicerName As String) As String
    Dim oSc As SlicerCache
    Dim oSi As SlicerItem
    Dim lCt As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.Volatile
    Set oSc = ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches(SlicerName)
    If Not oSc Is Nothing Then
        For Each oSi In oSc.SlicerItems
            If oSi.Selected Then
                GetSelectedSlicerItems = GetSelectedSlicerItems & oSi.Name & ", "
                lCt = lCt + 1
            ElseIf oSi.HasData = False Then
                lCt = lCt + 1
            End If
        Next
        If Len(GetSelectedSlicerItems) > 0 Then
            If lCt = oSc.SlicerItems.Count Then
                GetSelectedSlicerItems = "All"
            Else
                GetSelectedSlicerItems = Left(GetSelectedSlicerItems, Len(GetSelectedSlicerItems) - 2)
            End If
        Else
            GetSelectedSlicerItems = "No items selected"
        End If
    Else
        GetSelectedSlicerItems = "No slicer with name '" & SlicerName & "' was found"
    End If
End Function
```